# Issue with JPQL request take long time to execute with more then 600000 registrations

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a query in jpql that normally walk with a reduced data count, the problem is when the table to them over 600000 data records.
I use spring data, with an entity that contains no relation (no OneToMany, OneToOne, ManyToOne .....)with oracle as database..

I used JpaRepository, crudRepository, I even tried with JDBC directly, the return takes between 8 min up to 30 min.
I thought the problem was coming from the request, so I tried a findAll () and the processing time remained the same.
I changed the settings of the JVM -Xmx and -Xms to give more memory, but nothing helps.

Here is the request that I make:

public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository  {

```
@Query(value = "select new Test(CONCAT(t.date1, t.stringTarget, t.numInfo), t.name, t.phone, t.numInfo, t.date1, t.cotations, t.stringTarget, p.code, p.design)"
        + " from Test t, PointVente p"
        + " WHERE t.ePdv = p.numero"
        + " AND t.date1 BETWEEN :dateBegin AND :dateEnd"
        + " AND (t.state <> 'ANCL' or t.state is null)"
        + " AND t.game in :game"
        + " AND t.type in :type"
        + " AND t.participe = 1"
        + " AND NOT EXISTS (select t2.numInfo, t2.date1"
        + " from Test t2"
        + " WHERE t2.date1 BETWEEN :dateBegin AND :dateEnd"
        + " AND (t2.state <> 'ANCL' or t2.state is null)"
        + " AND t2.game in :game"
        + " AND t2.type in :type"
        + " AND t2.participe = 1"
        + " AND t2.numInfo = t.numInfo"
        + " AND t2.date1 = t.date1"     
        + " AND (t2.phone is null or t2.phone NOT IN (select b.phone from BlacklistTest b))"
        + " group by CONCAT(t2.date1, t2.numInfo), t2.name, t2.phone, t2.numInfo, t2.date1, t2.ePdv"
        + " having sum(t2.cotations) <= :target)"
        + " AND t.cotations > :target"
        + " AND (t.phone is null or t.phone NOT IN (select b.phone from BlacklistTest b))")
List<TestResult> findTest(@Param("dateBegin") Date dateBegin, @Param("dateEnd") Date dateEnd, @Param("game") List<String> game, @Param("type") List<String> type, @Param("target") BigDecimal target);
```

}

is it possible to reduce the response time?

May I have your help please.

Comment: I think your question is too generic. What have you done to optimize that SQL queries performance? Have you created indexes? You said you use Oracle DB, maybe you can use some Oracle hints in your query? 600k is not much.

Comment: try changing your repository's method's return type from `List<TestResult>` to `Stream<TestResult>`... would possibly prevent massive object creation (600.000 instances) - instead objects would be created on demand as you iterate over the stream. plz also have a look at this: [[https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-java-8]]

Comment: This sounds like a database management issue, where the access plan doesn't have good indexes. You need to learn to analyze SQL statements and create necessary indexes, so the database SQL optimizer can find the data faster. This is not, per se, a *programming* issue, but a DBA issue, so maybe ask on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ for how to improve the database performance.

Comment: I do not think this is a problem rated Oracle because when I run the request via toad, the return is very fast (1 ms), but via spring data, hibernate or jdbc, the return is very long. I forget to mention that I use ehcache to produce a cache DAO side, can not use the stream the project is in java 7,  and the table is well indexed